# Will updating my software to Mavericks delete all of my files and software?

Tags: software-update

I'm a new Apple user and have the option to update my software to Maverick.

I know that on Windows when you install a new operating system, all of your previous data is wiped out. It's pretty much a reformat.

Will the same happen with Maverick or will I keep all the data I currently have?

Answer (score 3):

It's always a good idea to back up your system before installing a software update, especially a major one like a new release of the operating system. That said, assuming no catastrophe strikes, your files and programs will be intact after installing the new operating system. While some prior version of Mac OS X offered several install options, including clean install, archive and install, and install in place, Mavericks offers no such options at the install menu, and by default preserves your files and programs.

However, not all programs will run the same under the new operating system. It is always possible that the install will break something (it did for me), and retaining a backup is a very good idea in case you decide you don't like the new OS, so you want to revert to the previous version, as I am about to do.